# '$ is undefined' error but the function works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am receiving the error '$ is undefined' from the first selector of js file. 
I have added JQuery reference as a local file or google CDN. Also I have tried to put it at the beginning and end of the HTML file.Have also checked the network part of the console to check if the JQuery is loading correctly.but seems it does not recognize the $. Have also tried to putthe whole JS file in $(document).ready(function () )
The function works correctly but I am still receiving the error. 
I have tried that with different browsers and different systems.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var currentIndex = 0;
 var itemAmt;
 

 function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.imageContainer div').eq(currentIndex);
  $('.imageContainer div').hide();
  item.css('display', 'inline-block');
 }

 var autoSlide = setInterval(function () {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > $('.imageContainer div').length - 1) {
   currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
 }, 3000);

 $('.next').click(function () {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > $('.imageContainer div').length - 1) {
   currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
 });

 $('.prev').click(function () {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
   currentIndex = $('.imageContainer div').length - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
 });
});
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.imageContainer div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.imageContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="HomeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/Slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <title>Home!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gallery">
            <section class="slider">
                <button class="next">Next</button>
                <button class="prev">Previous</button>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/400/200/people" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/400/200/animals" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/400/200/people" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/400/200/tech" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it working error free?

Comment: works for me without any errors

Comment: How many times are you including jQuery? 1 is enough ;)

Comment: Are you seriously trying to add jQuery 8 times?

Comment: @A1rPun I tried everything!

Comment: works for me without any errors, too

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn tried it step by step , one by one. thats the result

Comment: It works for me without any error. What you're saying doesn't make any sense. *$ is undefined but it works*?

Comment: You're loading jQuery 4 times in the head and 4 in the body. ***Don't do that.*** Load it once, in the head, *before* you load any script that uses it.

Comment: order or js files should be correct,starting from jquery and the other

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn for me works as well but I there is error in console! I don't underestand why!

Comment: When the error is thrown you can see exactly which file and which line of code caused it.

Comment: Why all the down votes?  It's a well structured question with all the right information to provide an answer.  Being ignorant of the mistake shouldn't be reason enough to down vote a question, or the community alienates new members who are here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jquery` should be included before all other scripts depending on it...

I suppose this is the issue causing `$ is undefined` error...

Answer (score 2):

Javascript files load in the order that they are added to the page.  The first javascript file you've added is `../Homepage/slider.js` and I'm guessing that it uses jQuery to do whatever it does.  This means it's referencing `$` at some point.  But wait: jQuery hasn't been loaded yet!  This causes the error you saw, because the browser might have started downloading jQuery already, but won't execute it until any preceding scripts are finished.

If you move jQuery to the top (and you probably only need to include it once, rather than 4 times at the top and 4 times at the bottom), this should fix your problem.

Better yet, move all of your script declarations to the bottom of the page, which means they won't block the rest of the page from rendering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../HomePage/Slider.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could also use something like [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to ensure the load order of scripts, but that is an advanced topic well beyond the scope of what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the jquery library only once. Since your jquery code is inside `$(document).ready(function(){` and `})`, you can can add it anywhere on your html code, but before any library which use jquery (maybe your `slider.js` does)